# Adding database module

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to django

I would like to start a project but when i run it i get this error

```
Error loading MySQLdb module
```

How do i add the MYSQL module or any other module for that matter

Comment: -1: This is **not** a Django question.  It's a Python question at best.  It might be a generic "how do I use a computer" question or a "total newbie" question.

Comment: Try using the SQLite database first to get up and running before attempting to use a database that requires installation.

Answer (score 2):

Install it on your system, using either a native installer or package, via `pip` or `easy_install`, or by running `setup.py` in the tarball.

Comment: If you are using a virtual environment, make sure you activate it before installing.

Answer (score 0):

you should install a mysql client and a mysql python client for that client. So you should execute following commands(For Debian systems)

```
apt-get install mysql-client
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Comment: The likelihood of the OP using anything other than Windows seems remote.

Comment: @Daniel: Cheeky =P +1 though ;)